# Should we get rid of "wood" in our tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just stumbled into tags which start with "wood" (by searching for [`[wood-*]`](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwood-*%5D)). It's obviously that all the questions on this site have and will have to do with wood.

Do our tags need contain "wood"?

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3/keeping-our-shop-clean), [tag:wood-turning] could just be [tag:turning], and even though I'm the creator of that tag, I fully support making that change.

Comment: While we're on the subject of synonyms: http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/63/192

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think unless 'wood' is integral to a single word ex. plywood, the word wood is unnecessary.

Comment: I agree. For example [tag:wood-turning] should be [tag:turning], but [tag:green-wood], should be as-is.

Comment: Actually, can we make [tag:wood-turning] into [tag:turning], but with the synonym of [tag:woodturning] and [tag:wood-turning]? What do you think?

Comment: That sounds good to me

Comment: I just ran into my question tag concerning "wood-movement" being edited to just "movement." I'm voting to reject, since I think the "wood" is integral to the tag. Please let me know if the community consensus is different.

Comment: @Doresoom You are correct. **Try not to get carried away with this naming convention.** Clarity should be the primary consideration when choosing your tag names. A tag called [movement] or [identification] is entirely ambiguous if you don't specify it is about wood identification or wood movement. This being a "woodworking" site in no way makes these vague tags more clear.

Comment: I'm agreeing with @RobertCartaino here (regardless of who he is :D - No cheese here, lol!). I think we should take a back seat approach and see how things shake out. Having wood in the title does bring a lot of clarity. We can have synonyms created if needed, or merge tags later. Let's let the site flesh itself out a little and see where it takes us. We may be surprised and it will be better than our wildest expectations.

Answer (score 0):

"Wood" is probably too general a term for tagging in most instances, but it occurs to me that some kind of tag is needed for questions specifically involving the wood itself. Questions like "Which wood should I choose for my project?" or "What's the difference between black walnut and claro walnut?" An alternative tag, if it doesn't already exist, might be something broader like "materials", which would cover questions like the ones I cited, plus MDF, plywood and other stuff woodworkers use that isn't wood...